# Reversing SHA-1 or MD5 given (small) input length without brute force

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash, md5, sha

I recall hearing that some weaknesses were discovered with SHA-1 making it easier to find the plaintext input given the output hash. I also know that MD5 has been determined to be weak for some applications. I'm trying to create a program to demonstrate the different complexities of 2 approaches: a brute force search to find the input, and an exploitation of a weakness in SHA-1 or MD5 to find the input.

The plaintext inputs will be of length <4 and will consist of only A-Z, so brute force isn't impractical.

My questions are:
Is there a C/C++ implementation to reverse SHA-1 by exploiting the weaknesses?
Is there a C/C++ implementation to reverse MD5 by exploiting the weakness?

My current feeling is that any approach to exploitation of the weakness will not have enough of a difference in time-complexity to demonstrate a benefit for such a small sample size.

Comment: Using an alphabet of [A-Z] gives you 26 possible characters. So you've got 26**4 = 456976 different inputs. Considering that even CPU-based crackers perform several million hashes per second, there is no point in trying anything that's not bruteforce.

Comment: @mfontanini My intent is not to create an efficient method to find the preimage, but rather to demonstrate the difference in approaches. Brute force would of course be ideal for such a small example case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a very detailed outline of a SHA-1 exploit, see

https://hashcat.net/p12/js-sha1exp_169.pdf

For such a small input sample, you can build an in-memory rainbow table of all possible input values and their hashes in milliseconds.  I doubt you would measure any significant difference using an exploit vs. brute force.

Further, for such a small input range, collisions are extremely unlikely (therefore there will almost certainly be no collision pairs).

Comment: I'm having trouble finding information on how to construct a rainbow table, so maybe you can answer this. My understanding is that a rainbow table is just a lookup table of precomputed hash outputs of a set of inputs. If the rainbow table will be generated at execution and will only be used to check 1 password, is there any benefit to a rainbow table over an iterative brute-force attack? (or are they essentially the same?)

Comment: it's not a useful technique for checking one password, no.

Comment: @SamTheSammich: There would be no benefit for looking up just one password, ever.  If you will occasionally lookup passwords, you could generate and save the rainbow table.  Having it on hand would probably be faster than brute forcing the next lookup.  For such a small input range, though, I would go with the approach that requires the least coding.  There will be practically no runtime difference.  If you get out to 7-8 characters with all alphanumeric and special characters, my experience is non-GPU brute force takes about an hour (depending on your hardware).  < 4 should take seconds.

Answer (score 7):

No, this is not possible. While some weaknesses do exist in MD5 and SHA-1, they do not generally permit preimage attacks of this form -- most of the known weaknesses involve the construction of collision pairs.